# Consequences of not updating the bundle version for an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, app-store

I submitted an update for one of my iPhone apps last week and just realized I forgot to change the bundle version in Info.plist before I submitted. The update fixes a critical bug, so I want to get it into the store as soon as possible. The app update has not been approved yet. I am debating on replacing the binary with the updated bundle version or leave it.

What are the consequences of leaving the bundle version the same as the previous version of the app?

Comment: Just a side-note on this, if you use Organizer (Product>Archive, then Submit) to load your apps, there's an automatic validation that will catch problems such as this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Apple may not accept the update as the bundle version is the same as what is currently on the app store
2. If it gets through Apple, iTunes will not automatically download or synchronize to the phone (you can see this behaviour using an ad-hoc distribution)

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised it even got through. I forgot to do that once, and itunes connect wouldn't accept my binary. I'd say you should leave it as it is, since you probably did change the bundle version in itunes connect, when you were uploading the binary, and so it should all work out. I'm not exactly sure though, cause I'm surprised it is even possible.